# Different methods to set the text of a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

What's the difference (if indeed there is a difference) between:

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
...
cell.textLabel.text = [self.adviceData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
...
NSString *text = [self.adviceData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:text];
```

They both seem to do the same thing, but one has more brackets.  Do the brackets do something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is just using the dot-notation syntax added in Objective-C 2.0. They both call the `setText:` method on the `textLabel`.

By the way, here's [an article](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=83) which will help you decide whether to use dot-notation syntax or not in your code.

Comment: I find the article rather biased. Instead of helping one decide, it presents an argument in favor of a particular point of view. They push this same view in their book, too (which is a very good book, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

They both do exactly the same thing, but the first one uses the alternative syntax for calling a setter (I'm ignoring the difference due to introduction of the `NSString *text` variable). Behind the scene, the compiler generates identical code for the two calls.